# Using RequireJS with node to optimize creating single output file does not include all the required files

Tags: javascript, node.js, faye, requirejs-optimizer

I use the [FayeJS](https://github.com/faye/faye) and the latest version has been modified to use RequireJS, so there is no longer a single file to link into the browser.  Instead the structure is as follows:

```
/adapters
/engines
/mixins
/protocol
/transport
/util
faye_browser.js
```

I am using the following nodejs build script to try and end up with all the above minified into a single file:

```
var fs = require('fs-extra'),
    requirejs = require('requirejs');

var config = {
    baseUrl: 'htdocs/js/dev/faye/'
    ,name: 'faye_browser'
    , out: 'htdocs/js/dev/faye/dist/faye.min.js'
    , paths: {
        dist: "empty:"
    }
    ,findNestedDependencies: true
};

requirejs.optimize(config, function (buildResponse) {
    //buildResponse is just a text output of the modules
    //included. Load the built file for the contents.
    //Use config.out to get the optimized file contents.
    var contents = fs.readFileSync(config.out, 'utf8');
}, function (err) {
    //optimization err callback
    console.log(err);
});
```

The content of faye_browser.js is:

```
'use strict';

var constants = require('./util/constants'),
    Logging   = require('./mixins/logging');

var Faye = {
  VERSION:    constants.VERSION,

  Client:     require('./protocol/client'),
  Scheduler:  require('./protocol/scheduler')
};

Logging.wrapper = Faye;

module.exports = Faye;
```

As I under stand it the optimizer should pull in the required files, and then if those files have required files, it should pull in those etc..., and and output a single minified faye.min.js that contains the whole lot, refactored so no additional serverside calls are necessary.

What happens is faye.min.js gets created, but it only contains the content of faye_browser.js, none of the other required files are included.

I have searched all over the web, and looked at a heap of different examples and none of them work for me.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to do this, I mist that on the download page it says:

> The Node.js version is available through npm. This package contains a
>   copy of the browser client, which is served up by the Faye server when
>   running.

So to get it you have to pull down the code via NPM and then go into the NPM install dir and it is in the "client" dir...